# Basic Navigation between views not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, navigation

I'm having some trouble with basic navigation between views.  I have a tabBarController with two views.  In the first view controller, when the method that responds to a button press is called the self.navigationController is null.  The debugger steps through the code but the screen in the simulator does not change.  I have the following code in my viewController button response method:

```
FooViewController *fvc = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated=YES];
```

In the didFinishLaunchWithOptions method of my MyAppDelegate.m implementation I am creating a UINavigationController and initialising it with an instance of a UIViewController as the Root View Controller with the following code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController1];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

My current understanding is that the initWithRootViewController variable should bind the UINavigationController object to viewController1.  What am I doing wrong?!?
Any thoughts, suggestions or pearls of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

-Munk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `initWithRootViewController` does bind the navigation, but then in the Tab Bar you should set the `UINavigationController` and not the `ViewController` itself

Change this line

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, viewController2, nil];
```

to

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nav, viewController2, nil];
```

Also you appear to have a typo here

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated=YES];
```

change it to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];
```